# JaxB - nested elements values are null

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am trying to convert XML to object using JAXB. Here is my code

```
<Root>
    <RName>jj</RName>
    <RID>55</RID>
    <Source>
        <Code ID="17">
           <Target Name="A" ID="20" StartAt=".01">
           </Target>

        </Code>
    </Source>
</Root>
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root { 
    public String RName;
    public int RID;
    public Source Source;
    
    //getter setter
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Source")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Source {
    public Code Code;
    //getter setter
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Code")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Code {
    public Target Target;
    public int ID;

}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Target")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Target {
    public String Name;
    public String ID;
    public String StartAt;
    //getter setter

}
```

JAXB :

```
File xmlFile = new File("Root.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext;
try
{
    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);              
 
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
 
    Root employee = (Root) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
     
    System.out.println(employee);
}
catch (JAXBException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can able to get RName,RID values, other values are null. Where Am I doing mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

For the Java properties (`Name`, `ID`, `StartAt`)
which are still null after unmarshalling,
you missed to tell JAXB that these correspond to XML *attributes* (like `StartAt="A"`).
By default JAXB assumes they correspond to XML *elements* (like `<StartAt>.01</StartAt>`).

You can fix your code by using the [`@XmlAttribute` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html).
So for example, instead of

```
public String StartAt;
```

you need to write

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "StartAt")
public String StartAt;
```

---

And by the way: It is best practice to begin Java properties
with a lowercase instead of an uppercase letter.
So you could better write

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "StartAt")
public String startAt;
```

You still get the correct uppercased XML attribute name (here `StartAt`)
by specifying `name="StartAt"` within the `@XmlAttribute` annotation.

The same is recommended for the Java properties corresponding to XML elements
by using the [`@XmlElement` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html).
like for example

```
@XmlElement(name = "RName")
public String rName;
```